# The value ' 1.500,10 ' is not valid for Price

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Web.config

```
 <globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US" />
```

Entity

```
  [DisplayName("Price")]
  public double Price { get; set; }
```

Create.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

I get this error when I add the product price.How can I fix? Thank you.

Comment: The string `1.500,10` is not a valid number in the `en-US` culture, you need to swap the `.` and `,` around, for example `1,500.10`

Comment: Same problem. The value '1,500.10' is not valid for Price.

Comment: The validation probably doesn't like the thousand separator too, try without that.